# What's the purpose of this quote here?

Tags: dont-look-up

Professor Mindy is shocked to learn that the ephemeris of a
comet keeps getting lower and lower. He sends his students
home and asks Kate to stay. Then, the screen goes black
and this quote displayed on the screen:

> "I want to die peacefully in my sleep like my grandfather not
> screaming in terror like his passengers"

It's looks the quote written by American humorist [Jack Handey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Handey).

What's the purpose of this quote here?

Comment: Well, the quote itself obviously implies that the grandfather was a bus or taxi driver, or airline pilot, who fell asleep at the controls and was killed in the subsequent crash when the vehicle no longer had anyone controlling it, but the passengers could see their fate and do nothing.  As to why the quote was used, it seems to be a comment on the fact that Professor Mindy has knowledge of the doom that comet represents, and that those who don't have that knowledge will die suddenly and thus, relatively peacefully, whereas he will thus have fear and anxiety for the (short) rest of his life.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quote itself concerns awareness of your own impending doom.  The grandfather is at the controls of some sort of vehicle (bus, taxi, airplane), and falls asleep, resulting in a crash which kills everyone in the vehicle.  The passengers are aware of their impending doom and powerless to stop it, hence the screaming in terror, while the grandfather apparently transitions from sleep to death without becoming aware.

Professor Mindy, having determined the comet's trajectory, is now aware of his own fate and his powerlessness to alter it.  The students remain unaware.  The quote equates Professor Mindy with the screaming passengers, and serves to underscore the horror Professor Mindy must feel, having foreknowledge of the impending disaster.